# Google Analytics and Microsoft Azure integration

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

Is there a way of integrating Google Analytics data and Google Adwords data into Microsoft Azure? If so could you please advise I have trawled the internet for solutions but I am unable to find anything.

I do not want to know how to put GA data into a data warehouse I want to know specifically on microsoft azure how you can do this using the data factory.

Comment: What do you mean with 'integrate'? If your question is if you can _use_ Analytics and Adwords in an application running on Azure: sure. They are just calling an external service. Otherwise: please explain what you're trying to do (and where you're failing)

Comment: Ok so I need to move data from Google Analytics into a Data warehouse. I am using the Data Factory feature of Azure to attempt to do this as I believe this is the bridge between the two and where transformations can be applied. I have tried to set up API management in order to bring in the GA data but have been unsuccessful.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this? I'm trying with Logic Apps, but not sure of the auth..

Answer (score 0):

Azure Data factory currently does not read data from Google Analytics. The full list of data store solutions supported by Azure Data Factory can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-factory-introduction).